# problema al exportar en mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

estoy intentando hacer un backup de mi base de datos y me marca este error en
workbench ya intente repararlo como dicen en algunas pag y sigo con el mismo error hasta desinstale por completo workbench y no lo puedo solucionar alguien sabe porque pasa eso???

agradezco su ayuda!!!

[image: error que aparece]
[image: donde se supone que tiene que ir mysqldump.exe]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! y que dice el log?

Comment: pues dice que hay un log pero no se a cual se refiere porque ya busque por todos lados y no hay ningun log que hable de eso o de ese error

Comment: q version de workbech estas usando?

Comment: La versión es la  8.0.16

Comment: ya lo resolvi tuve que crear una copia de el archivo my.ini a la carpeta de windows y con eso dejo de salir el problema y me dejo exportar correctamente